# Showing that $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$ is not rational

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Is there a short proof that $F:x^3+y^3+z^3=0$ in $\mathbf{P}^2$ is not rational, apart from using the genus? Perhaps this is an  elliptic curve, so every morphism $\mathbf{P}^n\rightarrow F$ is constant. Does this help me somehow?
As I said below, it seems that it is enough to distinguish $\mathrm{Frac} \ \mathbf{C}[x,y]/(x^3+y^3-1)$ and $\mathbf{C}(x)$, how can we do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the function field?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I see that the function field of $\mathbf{P}^n$ is $\mathbf{C}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and that the one of our curve is the fraction field of $\mathbf{C}[x,y]/(x^3+y^3+1)$ (taking the affine open $z=1$); but how to proceed? How can we distinguish these rings? In particular for $n=1$, we cannot use transcendence degree or dimension?

Comment: @Polynomialring Are you willing to accept the fact that if your curve was rational, it would need to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$? So, why can't they be isomorphic? Well, every affine open of $\mathbb{P}^1$ is a UFD, whereas $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^3+y^3-1)$ is an affine open of $F$ which is not a UFD.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $F$ was birational to $\mathbb{P}^1$, then because they are both smooth curves over $\mathbb{C}$, we'd have that $F\cong \mathbb{P}^1$. But, note that every affine open of $\mathbb{P}^1$ is a localization of $k[x]$, and so a UFD. That said, $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^3+y^3+1)$ is an affine open of $F$, which is not a UFD.

PS: You can show, in fact, that every affine open of the cubic you wrote down has infinite class group.

Comment: I have seen a similar argument for the curve y^2=x^3-x in exercise 6.1 in Hartshorne, but the proof that the coordinate ring is not a UFD was quite a drag. Is there an easy way to see it here?

Comment: if you give the argument that this is not a ufd, i will accept it.

Comment: @Polynomialring You have a factorization $x^3=-(\text{factor }y^3+1\text{ over }\mathbb{C}\text{ here})$. It's easy to show that $x$ and the factors are irreducibles, and non-associate.

Comment: @Polynomialring By example, you mean do the whole thing? What have you tried? If $x=f(x,y)g(x,y)$ in the quotient, then $x=f(x,y)g(x,y)+h(x,y)(x^3+y^3+1)$. How does that happen? etc.

Answer (score 4):

Two more ways:

1. The differential $X^2dX + Y^2dY = -Z^2dZ$ is holomorphic and nowhere vanishing on your curve. But $\mathbf P^1$ has no such differential.
2. (This one is silly.) Remark that permutations of $X,Y,Z$ or multiplication of either one of $X,Y$ and $Z$ by a cube root of unity preserve the equation. Hence there is a finite group of order $6\times 3^3$ acting on your curve by automorphisms. Does $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbf C)$ have such a subgroup?

Comment: I like your second, silly, answer. Unfortunately my group theory is a bit rusty, why does $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$ have no such subgroup?

Comment: Dear @Paul: Finite subgroups of $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbf C)$ have been completely classified, and I don't think that the above group is one of them. I don't see a simple argument to prove it, though. It's probably more difficult than it's worth.